# Unable to decode buffered response

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ascii, pycurl

I am trying to get the contents of a text file using `python` and `pycurl`. The connection is successful and I also manage to fill a buffer with data, but when I try to decode the buffer I am facing the following error message:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 644-646: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

def grabUrl(url):
  buffer = BytesIO()
  try:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.perform()
    if c.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE) == 200:
      # Successful request so try to decode the response.
      content = buffer.getvalue().decode('iso-8859-1')
    c.close()
    # More code goes here.
  except Exception as e:
    print ("Exception: ", e)
```

I am using `Python 3.4.3`, `pyCurl 7.19.3` and `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: Have you checked the headers to make sure it really is sending you latin-1 encoded data? There could be gzip compression or different encoding on the response body...

Comment: @MarekRost - Thank you for the hint, I will check the headers later this week.

Comment: @MarekRost - The reason for this seems to be that my locale was not set correctly. I generated a new locale, setting `LC_ALL` to utf-8 then the above seems to be working fine

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I'm facing similar problem with different encoding, didn't think of system encoding having play in that, so thanks too :)

Comment: @MarekRost - So, you had the same kind of error? Did you solved it by generating a valid system locale?